# Apps for facilitating live code demos?

Tags: demonstration

I really enjoy watching live code demos, especially when time is focused on what the code is doing instead of what the presenter is typing.  Many seem to be using apps to manage their clipboard to paste code into the IDE.  What apps are out there for skillfully managing your clipboard to seamlessly do a code demo?

UPDATE:

I found this app that Apple engineers use called *DemoMonkey*.  It's actually an [OS X app](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DemoMonkey/Introduction/Intro.html) demo for, ironically enough, the clipboard and system services.  The link includes the source so creating a PC equivalent would be easy, is there really nothing out there?

Answer (score 1):

It depends :

- if you're only looking for a better clipboard utility, you may try [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net) which is free and open source (and has a portable version, which is handy when you bring a USB key with your favorite tools with you everywhere :-)
- otherwise for webapp demos, it's useful to clean your favorites bar in the browser (even temporarily) and keep the shortcuts of what you intend to present there, that makes it easy to access from any tab; also, an online editor like the one of [Github](https://github.com) or [Cloud9](http://c9.io/) combined with saved snipplets (you can save snipplets with [gists](https://gist.github.com) or [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com) for example) can keep your code snipplets just a click away.
- for desktop app demos, shortcuts on the desktop and/or important files to demonstrate (e.g. to demo the import capibility of an app) are pretty handy

Beyond that, [Launchy](http://launchy.net) can be very handy to keep your shortcuts always accessible (whether it's for web or desktop apps) without having to break the flow of your demonstration by switching to the desktop.

Edit: Depending on the type of code you're presenting, services like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com) can also be useful because they serve as snipplets repository, online editor and execute your code.

Comment: ":-)" aargh unmatched parentheses! +1 for all else.